# Z3 Incompatible Sort Error when Using mkEq on EnumSorts

Tags: java, constraints, z3, smt

I have two constants `a` and `b`, of sorts declared using `mkEnumSort`, and when I run `mkEq(a, b)` on them, I get an error saying these two sorts are incompatible:

```
ConstraintGenerator.ctx.mkEq(ConstraintGenerator.smtMap(fSingleCol, fIndex), ConstraintGenerator.smtMap(pSingleCol, pIndex))
```

`ConstraintGenerator.smtMap()` returns an expression of sorts created using `mkEnumSort()`.

However, when I create an equivalent `SMTLIB2` file and run the `z3` binary on it, no error is raised. Following is the string equivalent of the above API call:

```
(assert (=  (PREREQ_COURSE_ID0 (select O_PREREQ 1 ) )  (COURSE_COURSE_ID0 (select O_COURSE 1 ) )  ))
```

How do I fix this issue? I'm using `z3`'s Java API.

Comment: Please post a minimum but complete code segment that causes the issue. Impossible to answer the without seeing your actual code.

Comment: @alias done. Please review.

Comment: This is by no means enough. See here for guidelines on how to create a minimal-reproducible-example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example